# Using grep with large pattern file

Tags: file, memory, grep, design-patterns

I just wanted to use grep with option -f FILE. This should make grep use every line of FILE as a pattern and search for it.

Run:

```
grep -f patternfile searchfile
```

The pattern-file I used is 400MB large. The file I want to search through is 7GB.
After 3 min the process ended up with 70GB RAM and no reaction.

Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong? Is grep not capable is such large scale?

Thank you for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try breaking the task up such that the grep process ends on each pass of the file. I'm not sure how useful this will be, however, given the sheer size of the file you're searching.

```
for pattern in `cat patternFile`
do
    grep "$pattern" searchFile
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If the lines in the pattern file are literal strings, using the "-F" option will make it much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that this is the first time I've ever heard of anyone using a 700MB pattern file before - I'm not surprised it ate up so much memory.

If you have time, I would suggest either breaking the file up into sections and processing each section one at a time, or even just processing the 7GB file one regex at a time. If you can fit the whole 7GB file in memory then, and aren't worried about how long it takes, then that might be the most reliable solution.